# How can I setup the mail network connection in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, email

I am trying the below command to show my current connection but there is not showing any connection.

```
sudo nmcli connection show
```

Please see attached screenshot for out put of above SS.

[image]

So how can I add it the network connection for it?

Output of `nmcli -g connections`:

[image: Output: "nmcli -g connection"]

Answer (score 1):

Your network has to be controlled via NetworkManager and not /etc/network/interfaces.

In debian testing `man nmcli` said :

> -g | --get-values {field1,field2... | all | common}
> This option is used to print values from specific fields. It is basically a shortcut for --mode tabular --terse --fields and is a
> convenient way to retrieve values for particular fields. The values are printed one per line without headers.
> If a section is specified instead of a field, the section name will be printed followed by colon separated values of the fields belonging to that section, all on the same line.

So, `nmcli --get-values connections` should work (root is probably not needed). Or     `nmcli -g connections`

Enjoy

Comment: I have run the command"nmcli -g connections" but I got the result according to attached screenshot in description

Comment: Could you post the result of 'ip a s' and 'cat /etc/network/interfaces'

Comment: result of 'ip a s' https://prnt.sc/xphdg8

Comment: result of 'cat /etc/network/interfaces': https://prnt.sc/xphimz

Comment: nmcli said 'unmanaged'... It seems to tell us that NetworkManager is not really the manager... 'ip a s' said you've network etc... and interfaces is configured to handle network parameters.

Comment: So, what's the real problem now ? Could you explain where or what you want to achieved.

Comment: I want to create net email setup using my domain name. example info@mydomain.com

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-mail-server-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I can't find my active connection by the command.

Comment: Is it a server box ? Do you need GUI ? If yes+no, you don't need NetworkManager : it's an easy manager for laptop (or desktop), not for server. Your've already saw your 'active connection' with `ip a s` (a shortcut for `ip address show`). And everything is based on the config in /etc/network/interfaces. If your system is Debian based, have a look at [debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryNetworkApplication%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryNetwork%29#The_resolvconf_program), and forget the "Configuring the current connection" part of the tuto.

Comment: Just add ´dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1´ at the end of your card's config in /etc/network/interfaces + reboot